# Ruby on Rails server isn't starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, localhost

I have been trying to run my Rails app using the command rails server
but recently this error has been coming up:

> Macs-MacBook-Pro:jobsboard mac$ rails server
>   => Booting Puma
>   => Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options Puma starting in single mode...
>   * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
>   * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
>   * Environment: development
>   * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000 Exiting /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:266:in
>   `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "::1" port 3000
>   (Errno::EADDRINUSE)   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:266:in`
>   new'     from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:266:in
>   `add_tcp_listener'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:260:in`
>   block in add_tcp_listener'   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:259:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:259:in`
>   add_tcp_listener'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:102:in
>   `block in parse'  from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:85:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:85:in
>   `parse'   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:133:in`
>   load_and_bind'   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/single.rb:85:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:51:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:296:in`
>   start'   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in`block in server'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in`server'     from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'   from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`
>   '    from /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/Web
>   Development/Ruby On Rails/Jobs Board/jobsboard/bin/rails:9:in
>   `require'     from /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/Web Development/Ruby On
>   Rails/Jobs Board/jobsboard/bin/rails:9:in`'  from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in
>   `call'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/Web
>   Development/Ruby On Rails/Jobs Board/jobsboard/bin/spring:13:in`
>   require'     from /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/Web Development/Ruby On
>   Rails/Jobs Board/jobsboard/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'    from
>   bin/rails:3:in`load'     from bin/rails:3:in `'

I can work around this by specifying a different port - i.e. using the command '

> rails server -p 4000

', but I wanted to use my old way of deploying it. How can I fix it?

P.s. I'm new on Rails, so please give simple instructions. :p Appreciated much guys! Thanks!

Addition:

> Last login: Thu Sep 15 13:55:52 on ttys000 Macs-MacBook-Pro:Ruby On
>   Rails mac$ ps aux | grep rails mac              1040   0.0  0.0 
>   2445080    800 s003  S+    2:02PM   0:00.00 grep rails mac
>   1020   0.0  0.0  2471272   3052 s000  S+    2:02PM   0:00.01
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.7/bin/fsevent_watch
>   --latency 0.1 /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.2.1 mac              1019   0.0  0.0  2462056   3032 s000  S+    2:02PM
>   0:00.01
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.7/bin/fsevent_watch
>   --latency 0.1 /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.1 Macs-MacBook-Pro:Ruby On Rails mac$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that port 3000 is not free. Another instance of your project is already using it.
So , find the process it by the following command:

```
lsof -i :3000
```

& kill that process by the following:

```
kill -9 processid
```

You can also remove the process id from the temp  folder of your applcation.

Alternatively, you can start the application on other port by the command `rails s -p 3001`

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal or iTerm and Assume you are already in your project directory.

Check PID process(es)

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

if they are exist then kill process(es), by type this on Terminal

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 0):

"Have you tried turning it off an on again?"

It's likely that there's a version of your app already running in the background. Have a look in Activity Monitor to see if you can see it, or if you're confident with your terminal-fu you could try

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

And see if it shows up there. Then use `kill xxxx` with the process id to end it which should free up port 3000 again for you